# How do you print from a popup window in javascript?

Tags: .net, javascript, printing, popup

I have a .Net application that dynamically creates a small HTML page and pops it up in a new window using the javascript document.open method.  Everything with that functionality is working fine.

Now I want to add a button to the HTML page that prints the page.  I have tried using the following code to no avail:

```
<a href='print.html' onClick='window.print();return false;'>
<img src='images/printer.png' height='32px' width='32px'></a>
```

When the button is clicked in the popup window, nothing happens.  But when the source code of of this page is saved and loaded in a browser as a separate page, the print button works perfectly.  <strike>So it would appear that the problem is caused by the fact that the code is in a popup window.</strike> [The problem now appears to be that the code in written to the popup window after it is opened.]  Does anyone know a way to fix this problem or any alternatives?

EDIT:

Other method that I have tried with the same results:

```
<input type='button' onclick='window.print()' value='Print' />
```

and

```
<a href='javascript:window.print()'>
<img src='images/printer.png' height='32px' width='32px'></a>
```

EDIT AGAIN:

The above code works in Firefox, but not in IE7.  Any ideas on a work around for IE?

EDIT YET AGAIN:

Here is a test case using the code that [npup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294150/npup) [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448676/how-do-you-print-from-a-popup-window-in-javascript/2460794#2460794) below.  Instead of the code for the popup window living in a separate html file, I am opening a blank url and then writing the code to it.  This step appears to be what is causing the problem.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>main</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        Pop & print</h1>
    <button onclick="pop();">
        Pop</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var POP;
      function pop() {
          var newWin = window.open('', 'thePopup', 'width=350,height=350');
        newWin.document.write("<html><head><title>popup</title></head><body><h1>Pop</h1>" +
            "<p>Print me</p><a href='print.html' onclick='window.print();return false;'>" +
            "<img src='images/printer.png' height='32px' width='32px'></a></body></html>");
      }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by creating a blank HTML page with the standard HTML markup.  I then added the content by creating a new DOM element and editing the innerHTML.  The resulting code is the same as in the example, simply replacing the newWin.document.write command with the following:

```
var newDiv = newWin.document.createElement( 'div' );
newDiv.innerHTML = "<h1>Pop</h1>" +
        "<p>Print me</p><a href='print.html' onclick='window.print();return false;'>" +
        "<img src='images/printer.png' height='32px' width='32px'></a>"
newWin.document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```

While the issue has been resolved, I am honestly not sure what was the exact cause of the problem.  If anyone has any ideas, I would be glad to hear them.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution that worked for me:

```
newWin.document.write( newhtml );
newWin.window.location.reload();    // this is the secret ingredient
newWin.focus();                     // not sure if this line is necessary
newWin.print();
```

I'm not 100% sure why this works but I think it has to do with one of the following: (1) an IE security issue,  (2) a scope issue (i.e. after creating a new document, IE is confused about which document to print), or (3) a timing issue - the document is not ready to 'accept' a print command yet. In any case, after the reload the print dialogue appears without a problem.

Answer (score 3):

It might be because you are doing a return false in the onclick event of the anchor tag.

Try this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.print()" value="Print" />
```

Comment: This had the same result, works in a separate browser window but not from a popup.

Comment: Hmm! When I click the button it opens up the printer stack for me to select the printer. Do you have printers attached? Maybe it is not able to find the printers? But anyhow it should open the printer selection box.

Comment: Did you try the code from a popup window?  That seems to be what is causing the problem.

Comment: yes my print button is inside the popup window! when I click the print button it opens the dialog to select the printer.

Comment: What browser are you using?  I just tested the site in Firefox and it worked.  But still no go in IE 7.

Comment: I am using FF and IE8. I have heard that IE7 is a piece of crap! It is filled with bugs.

Comment: Sadly, I can't force all my users to use browsers that are up to spec.

Comment: where to write the content that will be print

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
<input type="button" onclick="self.print()" value="Print" />
```

or:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.focus();window.print()" value="Print" />
```

But this might not work in MSIE due to restrictions in [Cross-Frame Scripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533028%28VS.85%29.aspx). The best way to do this, I think, is to put the print button on the main window.

```
<script language="javascript">
    var winref = window.open('print.html','windowName','width=400,height=400');
</script>

<form>
    <input type="button" value="Print Popup" onclick="if (window.print) winref.print()">
</form>
```

Comment: Neither of the first two methods worked.  The third method is not ideal and made more complicated because the code for the HTML page is generated from the .Net code behind based on various parameters.

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad tidings. If it were me, in the code where you generate the button/link that opens the popup, I'd create two. "Show Results" and "Print Results" or whatever…

Comment: It looks like I might have to head that way, but I am not giving up yet.

Answer (score 1):

There must be something more to it than the code shown. I think it works fine (been testing some now).

Here's a miniscule test case. Try it in your setup and see what happens! My checking was under Windows Vista, IE7 and IE8.

main.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>main</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Pop & print</h1>
    <button onclick="pop();">Pop</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var POP;
      function pop() {
        POP = window.open('popup.html', 'thePopup', 'width=350,height=350');
      }
    </script>

    </body>
  </html>
```

popup.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>popup</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Pop</h1>
    <p>Print me</p>
    <a href="print.html" onclick="window.print();return false;">
        <img src="images/printer.png" height="32px" width="32px">
    </a>

    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: This code does work on my setup, but it is not entirely applicable to my problem.  The major difference is that I am generating the html code for the popup at runtime.  Because of this, I am opening a blank window, then writing the html to it.  I will update the question with a test case using your code that still causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the:

```
newWin.document.close();
```

Document must be closed before msie can print it.

Answer (score 1):

This works in Chrome:

```
  <body ><img  src="image.jpg" alt="" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;">

            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function() {
                    window.print();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        window.close();
                    }, 1);
                };
            </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print what's in the window you opened *from*, i suggest you use

```
window.opener.print();
```

in the popup.

Comment: I am looking to print the contents of the popup, not the main window.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to create a printer friendly version of a page that then automatically printed, this is what I came up with, seems to work great for me!

```
 function printPage(){
  var w = window.open();

  var headers =  $("#headers").html();
  var field= $("#field1").html();
  var field2= $("#field2").html();

  var html = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>";
    html += '<html lang="en-us">';
    html += '<head><style></style></head>';
    html += "<body>";

    //check to see if they are null so "undefined" doesnt print on the page. <br>s optional, just to give space
    //This allows you to reuse this on lots of pages with the same template
    if(headers != null) html += headers + "<br/><br/>";
    if(field != null) html += field + "<br/><br/>";
    if(field2 != null) html += field2 + "<br/><br/>";

    html += "</body>";
    w.document.write(html);
    w.window.print();
    w.document.close();
};
```